# Unity. Загрузка спрайтов пользователем

Tags: c#, unity3d

Возможно ли разработать приложение, которое предложит поля для загрузки собственных спрайтов пользователю? При загрузке спрайтов, они "привязываются" к какому-либо коллайдеру на сцене. Потом это все двигается (возможно с анимацией, если нет- тоже ок).
Что стоит прочитать?

Comment: Можно. Думаю придется изучить API устройства что бы открыть диалоговое окно для выбора картинки.   Загрузить картинку по полученному пути.  А потом на заранее подготовленный спрайт вешаешь загруженный.

Comment: Я думаю вам следует просить пример кода, а не просить что-то прочитать, так как ответы ссылки запрещены.

Answer (score 4):

Есть парочка способов, но сразу оговорка: работает для одиночных спрайтов. То есть `SpriteMode` будет `Single`. Для анимации спрайтов нужно минимум их атлас или маппинг (mapping), который сделать в режиме реального времени довольно сложно ибо много нюансов как то: а как разрезать спрайты? Ведь в спрайтлисте могут располагаться не только по какой-либо ровной сетке, но и хаотично, как в атласе. Если разрезать спрайтлист, то где ставить pivot point у каждого спрайта? Как назначить конкретные спрайты из листа в *SpriteRenderer*? Каков должен быть масштаб? В общем, это будет кошмар и ужас. Поэтому лично я рассматривать сий вариант здесь не буду.

Для одиночных спрайтов:

- Для устройства, на которое нацелено приложение/игра необходимо узнать/изучить методы/способы открытия диалогового окна, в котором можно выбрать картинку и считать оттуда путь до файла. Это обширная тема, поэтому она здесь не вместится.

  **(!!!)** В данном ответе я буду рассматривать банально *Windows*.
- Зная путь файла можно сделать:

  **а)** Использовать класс **[WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/WWW.html)** для загрузки контента. Также, допустим, у вас заранее есть на сцене объекты под спрайты и просто в них нужно воткнуть спрайт.

  ```
  public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
  string directory = "file://d:/unityProjects/test/spriteTestLoad.jpg";

  void Start () {
       StartCoroutine(LoadImages());        
  }

  private IEnumerator LoadImages() {
          WWW www = new WWW(directory);

          // Ожидаем загрузку ресурса
          yield return www;

          var tex = www.texture;
          // Создаем спрайт из текстуры
          var mySprite  = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
          // В подготовленный spriteRenderer вставляем спрайт
          spriteRenderer.sprite = mySprite;        
  }
  ```

  Обратите внимание, что имя директории начинается с `file://`. Во всяком случае при загрузке файла в *Windows* с помощью `WWW` надо указывать именно так. Если загружать с интернета, то просто с `http`, например: `http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg`

  Здесь путь к файлу задан жестко, но вы держите в голове, что его надо будет просто заполнять из диалогового окна из пункта №1.

  **б)** Используя `System.IO;`. Пока также допуская, что надо спрайт воткнуть уже в имеющееся место.

  ```
  using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.IO;

  public class LoadSpriteFromOut : MonoBehaviour {

          public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
          string directory = "d:/unityProjects/test/spriteTestLoad.jpg";

          void Start () {
               LoadSprite();       
          }

          private void LoadSprite() {         
              byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(directory);
              Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(64, 64, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
              texture.LoadImage(data);
              texture.name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(directory);
              var mySprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
              spriteRenderer.sprite = mySprite;
          }
  }
  ```

  **в) (переделанный "а")** И не надо забывать, что можно создавать объекты динамически, поэтому подготавливать их заранее в *Unity* не обязательно (здесь используется загрузка из первого варианта):

  ```
  using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.IO;

  public class LoadSpriteFromOut : MonoBehaviour {

      string directory = "file://d:/unityProjects/test/spriteTestLoad.jpg";

      void Start () {
          StartCoroutine(LoadImages());        
      }

      private IEnumerator LoadImages() {
          WWW www = new WWW(directory);

          yield return www;

          var texture = www.texture;
          var mySprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);

          // Создаем объект       
          GameObject gameObjectSprite = new GameObject("myNewGameObjectSprite");
          // Прикрепляем компонент SpriteRenderer для спрайтов
          SpriteRenderer gameObjectSpriteSpriteRenderer = gameObjectSprite.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
          // втыкаем загруженный спрайт
          gameObjectSpriteSpriteRenderer.sprite = mySprite;
      }
  }
  ```

Ссылка на классы и методы:

- **[Sprite.Create](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html)**
- **[класс WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)**
- **[www texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html)**