# Подключение текстур в сцену с FTP - сервера

Tags: unity3d, ftp

Возможна ли такая реализация если да то подскажите в какую сторону копать: к примеру есть FTP - сервер, на нем лежить пакедж с текстурами в формате .fbx, и есть сцена на ней есть объект с пустой текстурой, нужно что бы при запуске сцены этот объект через код в реальном времени брал определеную текстуру из этого .fbx пакеджа который находится на FTP - сервере и отображал этот уже объект с текстурой.

Comment: копайте в сторону загрузки через https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html  ... там и ассеты загружаются .... и картинки с серверов и прочее.... что-то подобное на смежном вопросе сегодня писал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607814/  ......... только знайте что `ftp:// protocol support is limited to anonymous downloads only.`

Comment: Спасибо буду разбиратся, но если я правильно понял из строчки "ftp:// protocol support is limited to anonymous downloads only." я смогу работать с фтп только в случае если он будет доступен в свободном доступе, тоесть без авторизации.